# Is Waking Mars for Android the whole game?

Tags: version-differences, waking-mars

I'd like to try Waking Mars and noticed that the Android version is half the price of the Linux/Windows/Mac version. Is there a difference between them?

Is the game fully playable on Android, e.g. on the Galaxy S3? I haven't managed to find a demo.

Comment: While I can't say for certain, I can say I have played quite a way though this game thanks to the recent Humble Android Bundle and it doesn't seem to be trying to end any time soon. One of the few Android games I haven't been completely disappointed with in a long while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the whole game, but not with the highest-quality art and sound assets available, though that is set to change.

I bought the Humble Android Bundle and own both.

The PC Version has higher-res graphics, so you could say it takes full advantage of the bigger screen.

There's some direct info in this [entry on Tiger Style's blog](http://blog.tigerstylegames.com/post/35645251999/tiger-styles-big-big-weekend)

> You can also buy Waking Mars for Windows, Mac, and Linux directly from
>   us on the Waking Mars website!  We’ve said it before, but the game
>   surprised even us with how natural it feels on PC.  Kicking back on
>   the couch holding a gamepad watching it on the HDTV was a proud
>   moment!
>
> In addition to the regular technical and controls type work that goes
>   into a port, we massively upgraded the story presentation.  Check out
>   the improved character portraits, below.  We also added professional
>   voice acting which we’re really pleased with and we’re glad to see the
>   critics and fans digging it too!
>
> We don’t like to be stingy with our iOS roots, so we ported over all
>   this voice acting and art goodness as a major update to the iPad,
>   iPhone, and iPod touch versions.  It’s almost like a whole new game,
>   and as always App Store updates are free, so download and enjoy today!

Additional to that, [this tweet](https://twitter.com/tigerstylegames/status/274660983325216769), `Waking Mars on Android does not have voice acting yet. It's in progress but no ETA yet. Watch for updates here.`, indicates that the higher-quality assets will ultimately become available on Android too, but you might have to wait a wee bit.